# Why doesn't my PHP Code work?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I am trying to make it to where whichever row they click on, it brings it up in a new page called reply.php, but what is happening is it is only showing the content and subject from the newest one, not from the one the click on. Any suggestions? Thanks!

***Messages.php***

```
<html>
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styling/basic.css" />
<?php 
    require ("config.php");
    session_start();
    $username = $_SESSION['uname'];
    $userid = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `uname` = '$username'")or die (mysql_error());
    $id2=mysql_fetch_row($userid);
    $userid=$id2[0];
    $userlevel = mysql_query("SELECT `rank` FROM `users` WHERE `uname` = '$username'")or die (mysql_error());
    $level=mysql_fetch_row($userlevel);
    $userlevel=$level[0];
?>
</head>
<body>
    <br />
        <ul id="navmenu">
            <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>    
            <li><a href="messages.php">Messages</a></li>  
            <li><a href="#">Friends</a></li>  
            <li><a href="#">Settings</a><span class="darrow">&#9660;</span>
                <ul class="sub1">
                    <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Profile</a>
                    <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>    
            </li> 
            <li><a href="#">$<?php $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `uname` = '$username'"); while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){ echo $row['money']; } ?></a></li>
        </ul>
        <br />
    <div class="page">
        <h1>Messages</h1><br />
<?php
            if ($_SESSION['uname']) {
            } else {
                 ?><script type="text/javascript">document.location = "login.php";</script><?php
            }
?>   
    <ul id="tabs">
        <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
        <li style="float: right;"><a href="create_message.php">New Message</a></li>
    </ul>

<table style="width:100%;">
  <tr>
    <form action='delete_message.php' method='POST'>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='selectall'><input type='submit' name='deleteinbox' value='Delete' class='button'></td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><u><b>From</b></u></th>
    <td><u><b>Subject</b></u></th> 
    <td style="text-align: right;"><u><b>Date</b></u></th>
  </tr>
</table>
<?php  
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE to_user = '$username'");
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($numrows != 0){
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
            $msg_id = $row['id'];
            $msg_to_user = $row['to_user'];
            $msg_to_id = $row['to_id'];
            $msg_from_user = $row['from_user'];
            $msg_from_id = $row['from_id'];
            $msg_subject = $row['subject'];
            $msg_content = $row['content'];
            $msg_date = $row['date'];
            $msg_from_delete = $row['from_delete'];
            $msg_to_delete = $row['to_delete'];

            echo "$to_delete";

            if(!$msg_from_delete){
            echo "<div id='messages'>";
            $messagefrom = "<div id='leftside'><input type='checkbox' name='cb$msg_id' value='$msg_id'/>
            <a href='home.php?id=$msg_from_user' target='_blank'>$msg_from_user</a>";
            echo ($messagefrom."</div>");
            $messagedate = "<div id='rightside'>".$msg_date."</div>";
            echo ($messagedate."");
            $messagesubject = "<div id='center'>
            <div id='toggle'><a href='reply.php?$msg_id'>".$msg_subject."</a></span>
            </div>";
            echo ($messagesubject."");
            echo "<div style='clear: both'></div>";
            echo "</div>";
            $num += 1;
            }
        }
        if($num == 0){
            echo "<p style='text-align:center'>You have no messages in your inbox!</p>";   
        }
    echo "</form>";
    } else {
        echo "<p style='text-align:center'>You have no messages in your inbox!</p>";
    }
?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

***Reply.php***

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styling/basic.css" />
        <?php
            require('config.php');
            session_start();
            $username = $_SESSION['uname'];
            $userid = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `uname` = '$username'")or die (mysql_error());
            $id2=mysql_fetch_row($userid);
            $userid=$id2[0];
            $userlevel = mysql_query("SELECT `rank` FROM `users` WHERE `uname` = '$username'")or die (mysql_error());
            $level=mysql_fetch_row($userlevel);
            $userlevel=$level[0];

            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE to_user='$username'");
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                $msg_id = $row['id'];
            }

            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE to_user = '$username' AND id='$msg_id'");
            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
            if($numrows != 0){
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                    $msg_id = $row['id'];
                    $msg_to_user = $row['to_user'];
                    $msg_to_id = $row['to_id'];
                    $msg_from_user = $row['from_user'];
                    $msg_from_id = $row['from_id'];
                    $msg_subject = $row['subject'];
                    $msg_content = $row['content'];
                    $msg_date = $row['date'];
                }
            }
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br />
        <ul id="navmenu">
            <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>    
            <li><a href="messages.php">Messages</a></li>  
            <li><a href="#">Friends</a></li>  
            <li><a href="#">Settings</a><span class="darrow">&#9660;</span>
                <ul class="sub1">
                    <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Profile</a>
                    <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>    
            </li> 
            <li><a href="#">$<?php $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `uname` = '$username'"); while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){ echo $row['money']; } ?></a></li>
        </ul>
        <br />
    <div class="page">
        <h1>Messages</h1><br />
        <p>Message from <b><i><?php echo $msg_from_user; ?></i></b>:</p>
        <p><textarea rows="10" readonly style="width: 50%; resize:none;"><?php echo $msg_content; ?></textarea></p>
        <b>Response:</b>
        <form action="reply.php" method="POST">
            <br />Subject: <br />
            <input type='text' name='replysubject' style='width: 50%;' value="RE: <?php echo ($msg_subject); ?>" readonly></input>
            <textarea rows="10" name="replycontent" style="width: 50%; resize:none;"></textarea><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="replybutton" class="button"/>
        </form>
        <?php
            if ($_POST['replybutton']){ 
                $subject = $_POST['replysubject'];
                $content = $_POST['replycontent'];
        ?>
        <?php
                if ($subject && $content){
                    $date = date("M d, Y");
                    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE content = '$content' AND date = '$date'");
                    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                    if ($numrows == 0){
                        $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE id='$msg_id' AND to_user='$username'");
                        $numrows2 = mysql_num_rows($query2);
                        if ($numrows2 == 1){
                            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
                            $to_id = $row['from_id'];
                            $to_user = $row['from_user'];

                            mysql_query("INSERT INTO private_messages VALUES ('', '$msg_from_user', '$msg_from_id', '$msg_to_user', '$msg_to_id', '$subject', '$content', '$date')");

                            echo "Your reply has been sent successfully! <a href='messages.php'>Inbox</a>";
                        } else 
                            echo "No message was sent. An error has occured.";
                    } else 
                        echo "You can NOT resend the same message.";
                } else {
                    echo "You did not supply a subject and/or message to respond with.";   
                }
            } else
                echo "You must type a response to send this message!";
        ?>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have a database with the corresponding data sets. Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi while there is a lot in that code that could use work this is primarally your problem

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE to_user='$username'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
     $msg_id = $row['id'];
}
```

See you are overwriting `$msg_id` with each pass of the loop, as there are no other query conditions but the username, I imagine you get the record with the highest id, or as you put it the newest record.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response! That makes perfect sense! So what would I need to do in order to get the id of the one that I just clicked on? I appreciate the help!

Comment: you need to tell reply what one you want. I imagine you could use an id in your links like reply.php?id=1, then you add $_GET['id'] in there someware, but I would suggest using mysqli or pdo instead of the depreciated mysql, you should also sanitize your input etc.

Comment: Thank you very much! This fixed the problem immediately!

Answer (score 0):

In message.php change this line to:

```
$messagesubject = "<div id='center'>
            <div id='toggle'><a href='reply.php?id=".$msg_id."'>".$msg_subject."</a></span>
            </div>";
```

Comment: Hello! This fixed one of my other problems with something not showing up, but it did not fix the one I was having problems with in this post. Thanks for that though!